# Importrange doesn't import data from extensive sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, importrange, vlookup

The formula works on lower column number that I need to get data from but nothing is happening when I need to import data from columns with a higher number.

Following formula works (data imported from column 10)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A; IMPORTRANGE(Y1; "'Sheet1'!A4:DB"); 10; 0);))
```

Following formula doesn't work (I need data from column 160)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A; IMPORTRANGE(Y1; "'Sheet1'!A4:FZ"); 160; 0);))
```

My first thoughts were that it just needs some time but even after two days nothing is happening
**NOTE** - Y1 contains the sheet ID in my spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- well, 160th column is **FD** so try:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A; {IMPORTRANGE(Y1; "Sheet1!A4:A")\
                                       IMPORTRANGE(Y1; "Sheet1!FD4:FD")}; 2; 0); ))
  ```

Comment: error analyzing the formula. 

I have created two dummy sheets to test it on. #1
[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18CShoZzNGAbiRoeK4BboBKVn5RAxmTM-Mxsau2Chxxw)
 and #2 [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BM5NaQuYPUHBjMfQnc-jBe3_-A1gmkLfIUMXd5ApBPw)

Comment: @MarekMarhoul fixed. answer updated. check your sheets

Comment: It is working perfectly, thank you!